# How to hide actual path Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I'm building an application (Rails 3.2.8) where user can upload music tracks and associated clip. While clips can be publicly accessible, track can't be accessible without purchasing. I'm using carrierwave for uploading the both types of files. However, I do not want to expose the actual track path to the users.

What techniques such services use to protect hotlinking and/or unauthorized access to the files?

Currently, the carrierwave path is like:

```
  def store_dir
    "tracks/#{model.user_id}/"
  end
```

However, this is very vulnerable. Anyone can easily guess the url.

For authorised downloading, i can consider:
1. Static download link (this link is valid all time for that user. however, no guests or other users can use that URL)
2. General temporary links for each download!

Please enlighten me with the ways I can consider (i will study them) so that i can secure the files from downloading without purchases.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want both, public for the clip and private for the track.
I am trying to implement this as well with the approach below (not tested)

```
def fog_public
  return @job.job_kind == 'public'
end
```

Comment: thanks for your input. what is `fog_public`. Can you please explain or give me any reference?

Answer (score 0):

s3 allows you to store private file, they will be available only for a given period and with an access token.

With carrierwave, you simply have to set the `fog_publig` to false as described here https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3

Comment: thanks for input. but isn't it possible to do locally or without amazon?